# How to set draftcompile and/or optimize GWT compiling process in super dev mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging, optimization, gwt, gxt

I'm using Eclipse for GWT developpment(gwt 2.7).Actually i'm having a launch Debug Configuration that debug the application.Actually the compiling is done on the fly when i open Chrome the compile is done at that time.

My problem is that i did not find where to put the compiling options to optimize the compiling (like draftcompile ...).

Thanks

Comment: Super Dev Mode is already in draft mode - you can't really change it to not be draft mode, unless you want it to be less "super". What kinds of changes do you want to make?

Comment: I want to speed up the gwt compiler (-localWorkers 8,optimize 0 ...) where to put those parameters?

Comment: Super dev mode wouldn't be very super if it wasn't already optimize 0 - and more local workers won't help, since it will only build one permutation. This aspect of the compiler is not very multi-threadable, only the later part of building permutation can really use workers. Things that make SDM faster: less code, more ram, run in `-strict` mode (any errors make it recompile some classes every single time).